Sniff traffic between 2 devices
I have an Android phone with an app that controls an AV receiver, which sits on wired Ethernet that goes into a switch that goes into another switch that goes into the router, which also carries the wireless AP, to which the phone is connected. Everything is on the same IP4 subnet.
I can connect my laptop to any of these points, wired or wireless, and I have Wireshark on it. Currently it only catches broadcast and multicast messages from the receiver, and nothing at all from the phone. What are my options? I want to see the remote control app's traffic to the AV device. Thanks!

Is the switch managed, and if so does it support Port mirroring?

Are we talking about the first device both the AV receiver and my laptop are plugged into, or the router? The switch is a Cisco (or Linksys?) gigabit switch with PoE in 4 of the 8 ports, that much I can remember... the rest I'll have to check...

To avoid confusion, it would help to [edit] the question to include a diagram of how the devices are connected and the model numbers of the switches and the router. I admit that when I made my first comment "Is the switch managed..." I failed to notice the question text which said "that goes into a switch that goes into another switch...".

Right... both the AV receiver (target device that receives traffic I want to see) and my PC are connected to an unmanaged Linksys LGS108P

I think you’ll need to perform arp spoofing.
